# jQuery remove contains() text from div

Tags: jquery, html, contains

I want to remove all instances of

`<br />`

from my div. Using

> `$('div.std').remove(":contains('<br />')");`

does not work. I copied and slightly modified this right from the jQuery documentation site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try instead:

```
$('div.std br').remove();
```

This selects the `br` elements that are descendants of the `div` of class `.std`, and then removes them from the DOM.

References:

- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 2):

Just use this, it will find all the `br` tags inside `div.std` and remove it.

```
$('div.std br').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$("div.std br").remove();
```

edited the answer as mine was not correct after looking at the other answers

Comment: In theory this should work but it doesn't in case for some reason. I had tried this method already.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.std br').remove();
```

This will remove all of your `<br />` from all `div`s with a class of `std`.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be you'd need to rewrite it?

```
$("div.std:contains('<br />')").remove();
```